# How does Rack::Server.build_app add middleware?

Tags: ruby, rack

I'm trying to understand how a piece of Rack works.

In **lib/rack/server.rb** there's this line (344)...

https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/server.rb

```
middleware = middleware.call(self) if middleware.respond_to?(:call)
```

... and it looks like part of that line would be equivalent to:

```
Rack::ContentLength.call(Rack::Server)
```

... if we use Rack::ContentLength as an example default middleware (it looks like it would be one).

https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/content_length.rb
(line 14)

Am I reading this correctly, or have I missed something? It looks like Rack::ContentLength a) wants to be initialized first and b) wants a different argument for `call`, which is why I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Rack::ContentLength class in my example will be in an array when it reaches line 344 of **server.rb**. That array is controlling flow by returning false to `respond_to?(:call)`. logging_middleware on the other hand is not in an array and defines a lambda object that will `respond_to?(:call)`.

```
  def default_middleware_by_environment
     m = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []}
     m["deployment"] = [
       [Rack::ContentLength],
       [Rack::Chunked],
       logging_middleware,
       [Rack::TempfileReaper]
     ]
     m["development"] = [
       [Rack::ContentLength],
       [Rack::Chunked],
       logging_middleware,
       [Rack::ShowExceptions],
       [Rack::Lint]
```

I'll have to dig further to understand where/how those classes in their own arrays are processed, but it looks like it's not in Rack::Server.build_app.